# Wordpress and relative paths for CSS and JS includes

Tags: wordpress

I want to have relative paths on a Wordpress blog.

But i haven't found a way to rewrite **all** paths.

The paths of images, javascript, css files and so on.

For example:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://my-blog.nil/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>
```

in

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>
```

Comment: I hope jQuery is just an example...you don't have to include it on your page, as it's already included by default by WordPress (which also handles forming a proper URL).

Comment: Yes, jQuery is only an example. I need every Path, like my example, relative. No one have a solution? :)